# How do I add a time tracker to a ticket, that sends notifications to agents when ticket is overdue in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Here's the ticket creation code;

```
 public static function inbox(){
        $messages = LaravelGmail::message()->unread()->preload()->all();


        foreach ( $messages as $message ) {
        $subject = $message->getSubject();
        $body = $message->getPlainTextBody();
        $fromname= $message->getFromName();
        $fromemail= $message->getFromEmail();

        $mail =$message ->markAsRead();



        $ticketit = new Ticketit;
        $ticketit->subject= $subject;
        $ticketit->content= $body;
        $ticketit->status_id= '1';
        $ticketit->priority_id= '2';
        $ticketit->user_id= '1';
        $ticketit->agent_id= '1';
        $ticketit->category_id= '1';


        $ticketit->save();



        $mail= $message->to($fromemail)->view('mail.reply', ['fromname' => $fromname,'ticket_id' => $ticketit->id] )->reply();
```

How do I add a time tracker to a ticket, that sends notifications to agents when the ticket is overdue in PHP?

Comment: Look into CRON, (if on Linux)

Comment: i'm using CRONJOB to run that file.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to track the ticketid fro how long it has been open. If past due date..send escalation emails.

Comment: I don't use Laravel but obviously you will need persistent storage, such as a Database, that you can use another CRON job to check at a later time to see if it still open and overdue.  That said I can probably code it for you for an exorbitant fee!.  In other words what have you tried in regards to checking if a ticket is overdue.  Creating a ticket is all well an good, but that rather here nor there as far as the question goes.

Comment: The ticket has a created_at timestamp....I think i can use that to initialize time and if time++ exceeds 7 days while ticket is still active...then send notifications.

Comment: you'll also have to mark that the past due notice was sent, or it will keep sending it every time the second cron job runs, just saying.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of time identifier on your ticket, this could be in the form of a date or a timestamp. If you use the default Laravel schematics then you will already have a field like this that is named `created_at`.

Then you would have to [schedule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling) a task. As an example, you could create a task that gets run every hour that checks whether a ticket is overdue, and then email available agents or notify them within your application.

As noted by @ArtisticPhoenix, you will need some sort of tracking on whether a notification has been sent already, or it will notify agents every time the scheduled task gets run.

**Example code** - (untested)

This code goes in the `schedule` function within `App\Console\Kernel`

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $tickets = Ticketit::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->where('is_notified', false)->get();

        foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
            //send mail here
        }
    })->hourly();
}
```

You can further improve this code by adding a [queued job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues)

Comment: That's not obvious from what you posted in the question.

Comment: @Onderi Then you're half way there, then you only need to implement the logic.

Comment: @Classified That's the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix...sorry about that

Comment: @Onderi Added example

Comment: @Classified Thank you very much. I'm trying it.